# Basic python login failing due to runtime error

Tags: python, tkinter, runtime-error

When running the below code, the error `RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline` keeps appearing (line 6 - 'username = input...').

I am trying to create a *basic* pop-up login window that closes when the details entered match the stored value. If the entered details are incorrect, the window stays and the user can try again.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def login_function():

    username = input('Please enter your username:')
    password = input('Please enter your password:')
    print("Checking details")

    if username == 'testu' and password == 'testp':
        print('Username is right')
        winLogin.destroy()
    
    else:
        print('Incorrect username')
        #username.delete()
        #password.delete()
        login_function()
    
    return

#Create window and format
winLogin = Tk()
winLogin.geometry('400x250')  
winLogin.title('Login Page')

#Login labels
usernameLabel = Label(winLogin, text='Username').grid(row=0, column=0)
passwordLabel = Label(winLogin, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0)

username = ()
password = ()

#Login entry fields
usernameEntry = Entry(winLogin, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)
passwordEntry = Entry(winLogin, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)

#Login buttons
loginButton = Button(winLogin, text='Login', command=login_function).grid(row=4, column=0)

login_function()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10061#issuecomment-359972287

> If you are doing this in a terminal, you are using `readline` for the prompt and it is sitting there waiting for the user to type. `input` is also going to use `readline` to try and get user input. When you hit a key, Tk fires an event (in c) that eventually ends up calling your python function (from inside the tk event loop). You now have two places in your code trying use readline in the same process which is slightly un-defined

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: So because its running in a terminal simultaneously as the pop up, they are both trying to readline so it causes the error?

Comment: @JavaPuff yes, correct

Comment: I understand, how do I prevent the terminal from interfering?